# Cloudformation failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 51200

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Validating CloudFormation template using awscli

```sh
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://C:/path/file.yaml
```

returns

```
failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 51200
```

Is there a possible easy fix?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`validate-template --template-body` has a constraint of maximum length of 51,200 bytes (50KB). To validate a local file, filesize must be less than 50KB.

If you want to validate templates larger in size you can upload it to s3 and then use the `--template-url` argument. It has a constraint of 460800 bytes (450KB)

```bash
aws s3 cp $PATH_TO_FILE s3://$BUCKET_NAME/PATH
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-url https://$BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.yml
```

Comment: Your whole workflow changes to using your s3 cfn templates bucket. When **creating**, getting a summary of your template to making a **change set** you'll need now to first cp your template to the s3 bucket and then tuck a **--template-url**